# PHP: подскажите регулярное выражение для извлчения атрибута src

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Нужно через php у тэга img вытащить атрибут src, к примеру:

```
<img class="alignnone size-medium wp-image-63" src="/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/doorhan7-300x155.jpg" alt="doorhan7" width="300" height="155" />
```

отсюда должно вытащиться /wp-content/uploads/2016/09/doorhan7-300x155.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно поступить следующим образом

```
<?php
$text = '<img class="alignnone size-medium wp-image-63" '.
        'src="/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/doorhan7-300x155.jpg" '.
        'alt="doorhan7" width="300" height="155" />';
$pattern = '/<img[^>]+src=["\']([^\'"]+)["\']/';
if(preg_match($pattern, $text, $out)) echo $out[1];
```

Comment: А для `<img class="alignnone size-medium wp-image-63" src="/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/door'han7-300x155.jpg" alt="doorhan7" width="300" height="155" />` регулярка вернет `/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/door` :b

Comment: Если заранее известно, что все строки обернуты двойными кавычками, можно убрать одиночные кавычки из регулярного выражения и тогда этот случай будет обработан. Проблема в том, что предусматривая все больше и больше частных случаев мы усложняем регулярное выражение, это тоже не очень хорошо (особенно, если случай не реализуется, а регулярное выражение нужно поддерживать далее).